# The proxy name could not be resolved: 'http'

Tags: c#

I use the following script in order to download file

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357", 80);
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client.Proxy = wp;
client.DownloadFile("http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357:80", @"C:\Users\[redacted]\Downloads\DataDetail.csv");
```

I get error

```
[ERROR] Error: The proxy name could not be resolved: 'http'
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Er. I'd take a close look at your URLs if I were you. That doesn't seem like a proxy server. I would expect simply a hostname.

Comment: try adding a section in config like this --> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a57ed0f8-55ac-4b24-8d6b-5838ebdbc004/error-msg-proxy-name-could-not-be-resolved?forum=tfswebaccess

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola - Sorry, that has nothing to do with his issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name of the proxy server must just be a 'Host name' or an IP address only.

Examples of valid proxy server names:

> **my-proxy.example.com**    (Host name specified as a proxy server)
>
> **192.168.10.9**           (IP Address specified as a proxy server)

The reported error was shown as the specified name of `http://api...` is **not** a valid input for the **WebProxy** function.

**How to solve the problem?**

The problem can be solved either by removing the proxy server, or by specifying the proxy server as a hostname or an IP address.

**Working code without proxy server:**

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client.DownloadFile("http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357:80", @"DataDetail.csv");
```

**Working code with valid proxy server:**

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

// Valid Hostname specified as a proxy server
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("my-proxy.example.com", 80);

//  Alternative:   Valid IP Address specified as the proxy server
//  WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("192.168.80.80", 80);

System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client.Proxy = wp;
client.DownloadFile("http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357:80", @"DataDetail.csv");
```

Comment: where to find proxy ?

Comment: Proxy server, if already setup for the computer, can be found in the browser settings. (For Chrome, it can be found at Chrome --> settings --> proxy).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're wiring up a proxy (URL for proxy certainly isn't right if you need one).

I'm thinking you probably don't need the proxy at all:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357", @"C:\Users\[YOUR USER NAME]\Downloads\DataDetail.csv");
```

Notes:

- I removed the unnecessary `:80` from the end of the URL.
- The response given is JSON and your code is downloading it as a CSV.
- You instantiated an unused `WebClient`, which I removed.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: I get this error [ERROR] Error: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy authentication required.

Comment: Then you'll need a valid proxy URL. See @Gopinath answer for examples.